# PHP Oddities: Bypass Class Visibility?

Tags: php, oop

Today I was working on an old diagnostic library I had written back in the halcyon 5.1 days.  That library provided highly detailed dumps of any variable you could give it, using color coding to indicate types, and using Reflection to produce a lot of insight into objects (including, depending on what flags you pass, outputting relevant PHPDoc and even source code for objects - especially useful in backtraces).

At the time I been able to bypass member visibility to output the value of protected and private members of a class.  That proved to be quite useful from a debugging perspective, particularly with respect to detailed error logs we produce.

To bypass visibility in 5.1, I used the Reflection API, which let you see the value of protected and private members with `ReflectionMethod->getValue($object)`.  This of course is a bit of a security bypass, but it's not too bad since if you're going to view and modify values this way, you're pretty clearly breaking the object's intended API.

PHP 5.2 stopped Reflection from being able to access protected/private members and methods.   Of course this was intentional, and considered that ability to be a security concern.  I simply added a try/catch around this piece of my library, and output it if the language allowed it, and didn't if it doesn't.  Java Reflection AFAICR always allowed you to bypass visibility (I believe they are of the opinion that if you want it badly enough, you'll get it one way or another, visibility is just an advertised API for an object, violate this at your own risk).

As a thought exercise, and perhaps to bring my dump library up to date, I'm curious if anyone can think of clever ways to bypass visibility in modern versions of PHP (5.2+, but of particular interest to me is PHP 5.3).

There are three avenues which seem particularly hopeful.  First: mangling serialize/unserialize:

```
Class Foo {
    protected $bar;
    private $baz;
}
class VisibleFoo {
    public $bar;
    public $baz;
}

$f = new Foo();
$data = serialize($f);
$visibleData = str_replace($data, 'O:3:"Foo":', 'O:10:"VisibleFoo":');
$muahaha = unserialize($visibleData);
```

Of course it's more involved than this, because protected members are flagged as such: `null`*`null`Property, and private members are bound against their original class name: `null`OriginalClass`null`Property (see [PHP Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)), but theoretically you could clean those all up and trick serialize / unserialize into exposing these values for you.

This has a few drawbacks: first, it is fragile with respect to language versions.  PHP doesn't (AFAIK) make any guarantee that the data produced by serialize() will remain consistent from version to version (indeed, the way protected and private members are represented has changed since I've used PHP).  Second, and more importantly, some objects declare a __sleep() method, which might have unintended side effects of 1) not giving you access to all the private members, and 2) maybe this will tear down database connections, close file streams, or other side effects of the object thinking it's going to sleep when it is in fact not.

A second option is to try to parse out print_r() or other built-in debugging statements to scrape values.  This has the consequence of being incredibly difficult to do well beyond simple values (my old library would let you drill down into members which are themselves objects, and so forth).  Interestingly it's a variant of this approach that I used to detect infinite recursion (`$a->b = &$a`) using var_dump().

A third option is to subclass the target and increase its visibility that way.  This will get you access to protected members, but not to private members.

I seem to recall a few years ago reading a post by someone who had figured out a way to bypass with lambda functions or something to that effect.  I can't find it any longer, and having tried a variety of variations on this idea, I've come up empty.

TLDR version: an anyone think of some magic hoops to jump through to dredge out protected and private members of a PHP object instance?

Comment: Note that access specifiers are *not* intended to be a security measure!

Comment: I did at one point write a function that took advantage of this method ofs serializing/unserializing to convert instances from one object type to another (e.g. from an instance of a parent class to an instance of a child class). It's not something that I'd recommend.

Comment: @Mark Baker: I do actually have an implementation of this already, and it's problematic for the reasons I mentioned in my post (though it hasn't broken for any objects I've thrown at it so far).  The purpose of course though is not something to be used on a day-to-day basis, but more for introspection.  In part it's a mental exercise, and in part it's useful as a development tool to be able to deeply inspect your objects.  My team uses it to include detailed information with error reports.

Comment: Likewise: I only developed my function as a Proof of Concept, to demonstrate that it could be done, but never as something that should be used in production-level code (not even for debug purposes). For debugging objects, I use Reflection (with the getValue() method for properties with setAccessible() to handle private and protected) and/or dump a serialize() of the object to the logs. Serialize() does have occasional problems if you're using the magic __sleep() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fourth option:

```
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
```

can be used to make any property accessible using the getValue() method, even if it's protected or private. Test the visibility, then use [setAccessible(true)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php), getValue() and setAccessible(false) to reset.

I think this is a lot cleaner that a serialize()/unserialise() to a new class that has all properties public.... and doesn't require you to have duplicate versions of all your classes

Comment: I don't know how I missed this.  Now, how about reading protected static values =D (I know the serialize/unserialize model doesn't expose those either).  I've had luck with ReflectionClass::getStaticProperties() which gives all static values (including protected and private), while ReflectionClass::getStaticPropertyValue() does not.  I suspect getStaticProperties() will eventually take away inaccesssible values though.

Comment: serialize()/unserialize() won't expose statics, because they're class properties rather than instance properties... quite why getStaticProperties() and getStaticPropertyValue() work differently, I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note to anyone coming across this topic looking for a way for a debug script or whatever to blow open protected properties to have a poke about inside, probably the easiest and most far-reaching approach is to bypass the proper include/require system for the debug script and load the code you're debugging with eval(), as in this quick example:

```
$code = file_get_contents('ClassFile.php');
$code = trim($code, '<?php>');
$code = str_replace('protected', 'public', $code);
eval($code);
```

Of course you'll probably want to also replace private keywords with public too, and it would likely be a good idea to be more careful with your replacing code to avoid replacing the string 'protected' anywhere that isn't actually the protected keyword, etc. etc...

I'm sure I don't need to say that doing this on any kind of regular basis or for any reason other than development is far, far from best practice. However, this method of bypassing protected/private members is unlikely to be broken by updates to PHP any time soon, barring removal of the eval() function.